# How many times has the dust limit and minRelayTxFee changed?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, dust

I understand that there's no minimum tx fee or minimum tx output amount in the consensus rules. However, the default minimum values for a transaction to be considered 'Standard' in Bitcoin Core have changed over time.

Is there any record of what these minimum values were (for output value and tx fee) in previous versions of Bitcoin Core without having to dig through the code?

Related to that, what's the best way to find out about possible changes that may be made to these values in the future?